# Support GPS in Tablet not embedded

Tags: android, gps, location

I developed a search engine for location based on GPS and internet. Today I tested on a tablet that does not have GPS hardware, I traveled a few streets with 3G connection and my coordinates were captured accurately. But to drop the connection, I could not coordinate, due to lack of GPS hardware. In that case, I could do something to get my coordinates offline? I thought of something like install maps offline, and to read from it, it would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mock GPS](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) facility in android to test your app. Of course you will not get the real location.